# Java - apache commons exec, run 2 commands in same "context"

Tags: java, command, apache-commons-exec

I am unsure if context is the right word to use here but what i mean is something like

```
cd .\test
test.exe
```

test.exe is located in the folder test and I want to run it from the folder test, I know I can run

```
.\test\test.exe
```

but I need test.exe to be run from the folder test.

Is there a way to run both commands in the same "context"?

I have tried:

```
String cmd1 = "cmd /C cd test";
String cmd2 = "test.exe";
CommandLine cmdl1 = CommandLine.parse(cmd1);
CommandLine cmdl2 = CommandLine.parse(cmd2);
DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.execute(cmdl1);
exec.execute(cmdl2);
```

but as expected it could not find `test.exe`.

Comment: have you tried something like: `cd .\test && .\test.exe`

Comment: @SnakeDoc Thanks! that's exactly what I needed.  I should've searched how to run 2 commands in the same line instead of just searching for stuff about commons exec.  Can you move your comment to a post so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try executing both commands joined together using the `&&` operator.

Like:

```
cd .\test && .\test.exe
```

This will first change directories, and if successful, execute the `test.exe` executable in that directory. If the change directory is not successful, the second half of the command will not execute.